# Recycling solutions of multidimensional NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, interpolation, recursion, finite-element-method

Dear wolfram community,

I hope my problem is clear and easy to solve.

I have already solved the following heat equation over a domain:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

pde = 1/r D[r*D[T[t, r, z], {r, 1}], {r, 1}] + 
   D[D[T[t, r, z], {z, 1}], {z, 1}] - D[T[t, r, z], {t}];

\[CapitalDelta]z = 50*10^(-4);(*[m]*)
R = 5*10^(-2);(*[m]*)
\[Tau] = 3.5*10^(-3)(*[s]*);
Tw = 200;(*[K]*)
\[CapitalOmega] = 
 ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= R && -2*\[CapitalDelta]z <= z <= 0, {r, z}];

bc = {DirichletCondition[T[t, r, z] == Tw, z == -2*\[CapitalDelta]z], 
   DirichletCondition[T[t, r, z] == Tw, r == R]};
(*Note that the unspecified boundaries are set to Neuman zero by \
default*)

ic = {T[0, r, z] == 300 (*[K]*)};


sol = NDSolve[{pde == 0, bc, ic}, 
  T, {t, 0, \[Tau]}, {r, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

I optained an Interpolationfunction.

```
Manipulate[(*Plot mit relativen Farbspectrum*)
 Plot3D[T[t, r, z] /. sol, {r, 0, R}, {z, -2*\[CapitalDelta]z, 0},
  PlotRange -> {180, Tliq*1.1}, Mesh -> None,
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"r", "z", "T"} , 
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.001],
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
  (*ColorFunction\[Rule](ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#3]&),*)
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {t, 0, \[Tau], \[Tau]*0.01}]
```

Now I want to use the temperature distribution T[[Tau],r,z] as part of the initial value (T[0,r,z]) for a new domain (omeganew ) and then solve the heat equation over omeganew. The new domain is essentially the old domain but enlarged by an amount of 4*Δz:

```
 omeganew = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= R && -4*Δz <= z <= 0, {r, z}];
```

Here is the tricky part:
For the new solution I want the Temperature distribution from the previous solution to be "shifted" to the lower part of omeganew and a different function fc[r,z] (lets assume for the purpose of simplicity that fc[r,z]= constant) to be valid within the region that is newly added. So I need a shifted version of the previous solution with respect to the z-coordinate.

In a nutshel, I would like to extract the information (Temperaturevalues at an abitrary time t) obtained by NDsolve (e.g.  sol) to construct a Unitstep function (is there a better alternative?) that I would then use as the initial condition for the new domain (omeganew).

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What are the values of tau, R, deltaz, etc? Without them it's not possible to simulate. Please provide them.

Comment: \[CapitalDelta]z = 50*10^(-4);(*[m]*) ;\[Tau] = 3.5*10^(-2);  
R = 5*10^(-2); (*[m]*)

Comment: Please add them to your post.

Comment: ok I have added the additional information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. Let' set up the model:

```
Δz = 50*10^(-4);(*[m]*)R = 5*10^(-2);(*[m]*)τ = 
 3.5*10^(-2);(*[s]*)
pde = 1/r D[r*D[T[t, r, z], {r, 1}], {r, 1}] + D[D[T[t, r, z], {z, 1}], {z, 1}] - D[T[t, r, z], {t}];
Ω = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= R && -2*Δz <= z <= 0, {r, z}];
bc = {DirichletCondition[T[t, r, z] == Tw, z == -2*Δz], DirichletCondition[T[t, r, z] == Tw, r == R]};
```

If you now call `NDSolveValue` you will get a solution (looks like it's zero but that is a different issue)

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde == 0, bc, T[0, r, z] == 0}, T, {t, 0, τ}, {r, z} ∈ Ω];
```

If you evaluate the inteprolating function out side of the region you will get a warning and an `Indetermiante` as an answer.

```
sol[0, -1, 3]
```

[image]

```
Indeterminate
```

To change that you can use:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde == 0, bc, T[0, r, z] == 0}, 
   T, 
   {t, 0, τ}, 
   {r, z} ∈ Ω, 
   {"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {5 &, "WarningMessage" -> False}}
   ];
```

Now you will get the extrapolation value specified (5) and no warning:

```
sol[0, -1, 3]
5
```

With this you can then call `NDSolveValue` on a different domain with a different initial value like so:

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{pde == 0, bc, T[0, r, z] == sol[τ, r, z]}, 
   T, 
   {t, 0, τ}, 
   {r, z} ∈ ImplicitRegion[ 0 <= r <= R && -10*Δz <= z <= 0, {r, z}]
   ];
```

Comment: OHH I also forgot to provide the values for Tw and ic (The "wall temperature" and the initial temperature distribution respectively . They are now included in the post!

Comment: I want sol[tau, r, z] to be the intial value for the domain1: 0 <= r <= R && -4*Δz <= z <= -Δz  (e.g.sol[tau, 0, 0]=T[0,0,-Δz ],sol[tau, 0, -0.5*Δz ]=T[0,0,-0.5*Δz -Δz ] ,and so forth) I want to essentially shift the function downwards. And the initial values of the domain2  0 <= r <= R && -Δz <= z <= 0 to be specified by a completely different function ( lets say a constant) Of course  sol2 is to be solved for the union of domain1 and domain2

Comment: @GustavoMeyagan, you need to specify everything in the question. Try to do this in a clean, clear way such that people can follow your line of thought.

Comment: @User21I think I've figured out the problem. The interpolation function obtained from NDSolve does not enable you to obtain the value at arbitrary points, for exaple sol[0, -1, 3] will not give the value 5. One actually needs to solve the pde with NDSolveValue instead. From there you can use sol[t,r,z] like any other function including embedding it in a unitstep function.Thank you very much for your help! You guys rock!

Comment: @GustavoMeyagan, good that you figured it out. `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue` essentially return the same result. `NDSolve` will give you a Rule where the second argument is the interpolating function. To use the result from `NDSolve` you first need to replace the dependent variable to get to the interpolating function. With `NDSolveValue` there is not such need as it directly returns the Interpolating function.

Comment: @GustavoMeyagan, also `NDSolve` rocks! ;-)